# Copy SQL data that has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird request as I support an application that does purging of historical data routinely which I would like to store in a separate datastore.  I want to keep the schema of the database in the copy identical however I would like to be able to script a process which could take the changes to the primary database and replicate to the clone without deleting the data that the application is purging from the database tables.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You say "replicate", I think [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication). Specifically, replication where you exclude deletes from being replicated.

Comment: You could probably use Change Data Capture as well. Compared to replication, it's far more simple with less maintenance. However, as a trade-off, you'll need to write custom queries to get the data from CDC.

Comment: Seems like a good option to peruse is also triggers - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: @Angelo - definite no to triggers however I was thinking about a stored proc using merge functionality.

Comment: @JacobH - explain CDC?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - not true replication as I want to keep values that were deleted from the master DB in the copy.

Comment: I don't know what you consider "true" replication, but replication is highly configurable. Aside from having the option to simply not replicate delete statements at all, you can also have it invoke custom stored procedures instead of replicating commands directly, if you need custom logic for updates as well. (It is true that the more you customize it, the less convenient replication becomes; it's easiest if you just want a 1-1 copy.)

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking was custom stored procs doing a merge where i am ignoring deletes however my fear is it will then fail due to PK/FK links on the db side

Comment: Typically you do not want FKs present on replicated data simply because the potential for failure is so high (and there's `NOT FOR REPLICATION` exactly for that purpose); the responsibility for keeping everything consistent even if the source data gets out of sync is a big one. This is true regardless of whether you use the built-in replication or your own custom process, though. PKs are still fine -- replication will only break on rows it wants to insert that are already there; modifications on rows that are no longer there will simply do nothing.

Comment: cool so I should just look at keeping the PKs and then remove all the other constraints and when I setup my stored prod ensure that I cascade the relevant tables if required?

Comment: SymmetricDS is a highly configurable replication tool that can handle such configurations to not replicate deletes to the target etc.   It might provide the configuration flexibility you are looking for while auto resolving foreign key issues.